# How to Unit Test a project with Multiple Configurations

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

Inside the the TestCase files we always import the Product Name of the product we are testing, example:

```
@testable import FooApp
import XCTest
```

The problem that I have is that I have multiple Product Names because I have different configurations

[image: Configurations]

The error message generated for this is `No Such module <product module name>` and that's because of the different `$PRODUCT_NAME`s that I have setup for my different configurations.

Is there a way I can make the `@testable import` modular so that I can run my Tests on all of the configurations?

Below is an example of how I set my `Product Bundle Id`, `Product Module Name`, and `Product Name`.

[image]

Is there a way I can do something like the example below?

```
@testable import SomeWildCardHere
import XCTest
```

Because the alternative would be to do something like the example below.

```
#if DEVELOP
@testable import App_Dev
#elseif STAGING
@testable import App_Stg
#elseif TEST
@testable import App_Tst
#else
@testable import App
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME` does not need to be different for each configuration. This would mean that I can just have just one import for all configurations. Though I'm not sure how what if there will be bad effects in the projects moving forward.

```
@testable import App // for all targets
```

Take Note: Don't change your `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME` for a production app because it **strong text**